# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

QueryException in Connection.php line 769:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hmsdb.customers' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `customers` (`lastName`, `firstName`, `middleName`, `address`, `telephone`, `mobile`, `notes`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Arce, Johanna, , ds, N/A, ds, ew, 2016-12-05 09:20:18, 2016-12-05 09:20:18))

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hmsdb.customers' doesn't exist

The name of the column should be customer and i don't where how to change hmsdb.customers to hmsdb.customer

Comment: in your model `protected $table='customer';`

Answer (score 5):

In your customer model change to it like `protected $table = 'customer';` 
Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This was correct. In the customer mode, the table namel was wrongly spelled.

Answer (score 0):

check your table name. its showing error as table not found there is spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you have located the migration of the table in a specific folder, you must indicate the path and then add the command --seed to execute the filling of your table.

example:
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/your_migration.php --seed